# google.maps.LatLng vs google.maps.LatLngLiteral

Tags: google-maps

I am adding google maps to an application I am working on and have successfully gotten myself stuck on a question that may have no impact whatsoever on my application.

Regardless, I am curious why Google Maps allows you to use
    `new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)`
or 
    `{lat: x, lng: y}`

I have used both formats and see absolutely no difference but I feel as though I must be missing something... I cannot believe google.map.LatLng exists with no specific purpose.

This:

```
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    center: chicago
  }
```

Or this:

```
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = {lat: 41.850033, lng: -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    center: chicago
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) is the original class (the earliest versions of the API didn't have the `google.maps.LatLngLiteral`), most but not all, functions that accept a `google.maps.LatLng` also accept a [`google.maps.LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) (`{lat: x, lng: y}`).

- The advantage of a `google.maps.LatLngLiteral` is it doesn't require the API to be loaded to use it, it can be used and initialized prior to loading the API.
- The advantage of a `google.maps.LatLng` is that some functions (primarily those in the [`geometry` library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry)) only accept `google.maps.LatLng` as inputs.